# How to check whether Spring Cloud data flow microservice is up by using Python

Tags: python-3.x, spring-cloud-dataflow

Is there a way to check whether Spring Cloud data flow (streams) microservice is up and running by using Python?
I would also want to (un)deploy microservice.

Is it possible?

Comment: Hi, Can you elaborate a little more on your use case? Are you planning to use python based streaming app as one of the apps inside a streaming pipeline in SCDF?

Comment: I would like to use python for managing micro services written in any language. Let's say that micro service A is written in Java. I would like by using python to find out whether micro service is up and running, and if it is not running to bring it up.

Comment: ok, looks like you want to add the platform capabilities to your python code to take care of managing your applications. While it could be possible, I am not skilled enough on Python to answer how. Let's see the other answers.

Comment: Is there api for such things. I can't find any info, but I am not that much familiar with Spring Cloud data flow. If someone can point me towards api, that would be more than enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [REST API guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#api-guide) to understand what REST endpoints you can use to specify operations against Spring Cloud Data Flow (start/stop the stream/task for instance).

Comment: It could be what I need. Thank you very much.